# scatter and histogram on same plot in r

Tags: r, plot, histogram, scatter

I am plotting a scatter plot between say X and Y. (X on x-axis and Y on y-axis) using following syntax.

plot(X, Y)

***X and Y both are continuous variables.***

Now, I want to get a frequency plot (histogram) over this scatter plot. For eg. let us say X in the scatter plot is ranging from 0 to 5. So, I want to get a frequency plot for each interval of length 1 of X. So, for X in [0-1] there will be one bar, for X in [1-2] second bar, for X in [2-3] third bar and so on.

**EDIT:** 
***Histogram may cover up most of the scatter. So, even if I get numbers corresponding to bar written somewhere on the plot (say at the top) would also do (no bars in this case). I just need to get an idea of frequency for different ranges (as bars or just numbers).***

How can achieve this in R?

dput of a very small sample.

```
structure(list(X = c(0.00141030838064132, 0.000494776986570204, 
0.000420637540743273, 0.000416330553562312, 0.000327605678810922, 
0.000334769111670038, 0.000176362745989615, 0.000353032500825868, 
0.000284234369907286, 8.1733706680748e-05, 0.00040641582048246, 
8.11457783908792e-05, 8.0837382794669e-05, 0.000180929590411692, 
7.34138519774738e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 0.000180489447700001, 
8.11457783908792e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 
7.59364670335551e-05, 8.11366624312646e-05, 8.07716946874238e-05, 
8.11457783908792e-05, 7.94865358399697e-05, 8.11363186345391e-05, 
8.08682289898023e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 
8.10380699582227e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 
8.10597920106679e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 7.99543191487116e-05, 
8.11457783908792e-05, 8.04154336817913e-05, 8.11040375814918e-05, 
8.11457783908792e-05, 8.11457783908792e-05, 0.000115930065130829, 
0, 0.00149708061666934, 0.000259968018664645, 0.000252569769878596, 
0.000272319502600671, 1.55688321576032e-05, 0.00288760062956232, 
0.000231670000469685, 7.83115248647628e-05, 0.000640384230538323, 
0.000698932964979634, 0.000595671591321322, 0.000538765242449338, 
0.000765226541647779, 0.000587799953746904, 0.000655947982777194, 
0.000402366287651635, 0.00063891536109952, 0.000213812430974318, 
0.000564814230989396, 0.000201566507273599, 0.000542942589765765, 
0.000640384230538323, 0.000640384230538323, 0.000640384230538323, 
0.000910553716031754, 0.000722077439151928, 0.000474200650778307, 
0.000116662171252828, 0, 0, 0.000142960473164439, 0, 8.46636778817535e-05, 
0, 0, 0.00118718015299255, 0.000458686951174685, 0.000139951761307805, 
0.000412851997311128, 8.85804022332864e-05, 0.000301084760362437, 
2.81047907806604e-05, 0.000139526441696557, 0.000128095170697041, 
6.90398423104225e-05, 1.45278932213477e-05, 0.000121815916084411, 
0.00014369483584908, 0, 0.000118108327984086, 5.84788165557941e-05, 
0.000129959996409527, 0.000133080075718582, 0.00013192258835621, 
0.000132535040379761, 0.000232951960667621, 0.000132356598534841, 
0.000133682865059176), Y = c(2.44160223530961e-06, 4.32697911760654e-07, 
7.28671581824204e-07, 7.84051631144022e-07, 1.49857280230364e-07, 
4.42449893419501e-07, 3.60364826955947e-07, 4.66191261960537e-07, 
3.16997496383143e-07, 2.37850594276965e-07, 4.27127571638305e-07, 
1.8043281515139e-07, 1.58857206660122e-07, 1.01436449014835e-07, 
2.19121836415415e-07, 9.17178201531101e-08, 8.1055328062058e-08, 
1.08543082127821e-07, 2.37371597342348e-07, 2.24014612697305e-07, 
1.80966979034231e-07, 1.72812312121038e-07, 2.45547707661429e-07, 
1.75937297851997e-07, 1.86798308192844e-07, 1.5298361416559e-07, 
1.63279483827935e-07, 1.00573634637651e-07, 7.13682637405445e-08, 
2.39123470964322e-07, 2.26638075403414e-07, 1.83133361992077e-07, 
2.04672970252807e-07, 4.6181672198457e-08, 1.39358166991606e-07, 
1.97063969072651e-07, 8.56155084029855e-08, 1.06540549772715e-07, 
8.87443726998921e-08, 7.04813613555759e-08, 1.30594177490294e-07, 
7.62557591852037e-08, 1.43634658915428e-06, 1.59657677606683e-07, 
1.45064318575815e-07, 1.97426903401167e-07, 8.33922027413303e-08, 
1.01595071050062e-06, 4.23237426396923e-07, 5.02256932665429e-08, 
5.3136081345117e-07, 8.84595841358677e-07, 2.57979560107636e-07, 
5.48895545821489e-07, 3.78459760153572e-07, 2.51220673457457e-07, 
7.93205331143823e-07, 7.08644863444902e-07, 4.75314501123384e-07, 
3.1824555227723e-07, 2.1736608233363e-07, 2.10137999981753e-07, 
3.41783665158596e-07, 8.39520233762751e-07, 5.36586936905755e-07, 
8.35734279442903e-07, 1.42006858503491e-06, 8.81082298452859e-07, 
4.58820539595698e-07, 2.03280871672928e-07, 1.03031416892225e-07, 
1.13090922158804e-07, 5.2333059218234e-08, 8.39086473222456e-08, 
8.65586947570376e-08, 7.20426881871566e-08, 1.00987474738825e-07, 
8.70845576365621e-07, 2.15037446443111e-07, 1.16765276937208e-07, 
5.69984738663679e-07, 1.27528196133943e-07, 5.2860614256513e-07, 
4.95092076627282e-08, 1.66774637700855e-07, 2.59807590834898e-07, 
2.15927807826023e-07, 1.35475385072329e-07, 8.04043348820979e-08, 
8.62621147081329e-08, 1.05998625390818e-07, 1.15756288940413e-07, 
1.63617432597157e-07, 1.15577606551361e-07, 8.75307480186725e-08, 
2.19571702322701e-07, 6.61603492359945e-08, 2.71772452724646e-07, 
1.59606589766817e-07, 1.81449721904323e-07)), .Names = c("X", 
"Y"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Won't your histogram cover up a bunch of your scatterplot points? What have you tried so far? Are you using base graphics or some other package? Do you have some example data?

Comment: Yes. Histogram may cover up most of the scatter. So, even if I get numbers corresponding to bar written somewhere on the plot would also do (no bars in this case). I just need to get an idea of frequency for different ranges as bars or numbers. And I am currently using base package only. I will provide a sample data in a bit.

Comment: how do i attach my data? my data has 1000 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = randu * 10   # load some data
h = hist(x$x, breaks = max(x$x)-min(x$x))  # plot a histogram
par(new=TRUE)  # new plot
plot(x$x, x$y,,type="p",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
           # plot your points but no axes
axis(4)    # draw axis on side "4"
```

randu is just some data.  I multiplied it be 10 to demo the breaks you want.
hist, plots the histogram.  h contains data you're interested in too.  Breaks gives you the number of bins to put your data in... in this case the range of the data, which will give bins of width 1.

[image: with example data]

**UPDATE**

With your data:

```
h = hist(x$X, breaks = 15)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(x$X, x$Y,,type="p",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
```

gives me:

[image: With user sample data]

(I put your data into x, obviously)

**Also**

you might want to view your data log-tranformed... it's quite bunched up!

```
l = log2(x)
h = hist(l$X, breaks = 15)
par(new=TRUE)
plot(l$X, l$Y,,type="p",col="blue",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="")
axis(4)
```

[image: log transformed]

Comment: on my data, right side labels are not aligning properly. they are a little down.

Comment: but breaks could be a non integer as per your calculation.

Comment: what is the range of your y-data?

Comment: Can you tell me how do I upload my data here? Not seeing any option to upload.

Comment: no idea, sorry.  Most times I've seen people actually post the data :S    Yes, the breaks *can* be non-integer, and is rounded accordingly.  e.g. breaks=9.9 gives you 10 bins.  Actually, the rounding is done so the bin sizes are sensible (e.g. 1, 2, 0.5, etc)

Comment: In my case (on real data on which I have to do it), actually min and max values of Y are 2.615071e-08 and 3.460165e-06. In this case, what would the break be? You can ignore the break of length 1 in the question, I wrote that for simplifying question.

Comment: In our example, the break is for the x values only...  R: ?hist says this:  " the number is a suggestion only; the breakpoints will be set to pretty values. If breaks is a function, the x vector is supplied to it as the only argument."

Comment: I just paste the dput of a small 100 rows sample. Can you please try on that?